# Yii2 module custom response class

Tags: php, yii2

I have defined a custom response class and was trying to use it in a module.

In the controller action i return an array of results, but the custom response class isn't used.

Instead, the class used is the default yii\web\Response

**My implementation**

The module configuration in config/web.php:

```
'mymodule' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\mymod\Mymod',
        'components' => [                
            'response' => [
                'class' => 'app\modules\mymod\components\apiResponse\ApiResponse',
                'format' => yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                'charset' => 'UTF-8',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

In the controller i edited the behaviors method:

```
public function behaviors() {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();        
    $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',            
        'response' => $this->module->get('response'),                
        'formats' => [  //supported formats
            'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        ],
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

In the action if i do:

```
public function actionIndex() {

    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    $dataList = [
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John', 'surname' => 'Davis'],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Marie', 'surname' => 'Baker'],
        ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Albert', 'surname' => 'Bale'],
    ];
    return $dataList;
}
```

I get this result (as expected from yii\web\Response):

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Davis"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Marie",
    "surname": "Baker"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Albert",
    "surname": "Bale"
}
]
```

But if i change the action to this:

```
$dataList = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John', 'surname' => 'Davis'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Marie', 'surname' => 'Baker'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Albert', 'surname' => 'Bale'],
];
//return $dataList;

$resp = $this->module->get('response'); //getting the response component from the module configuration
$resp->data = $dataList;

return $resp;
```

Then i get the expected result, which is this:

```
{
"status": {
    "response_code": 0,
    "response_message": "OK",
    "response_extra": null
},
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Davis"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Marie",
        "surname": "Baker"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Albert",
        "surname": "Bale"
    }
]}
```

It seems the behaviors i defined aren't doing anything.

What do i need to do to just return the array in the action and the custom response component is used?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`yii\base\Module` does not have response component, so your configuration will not work. 
Instead of adding `response` component into your module You sould change `Yii::$app->response` inside `MyMod::init()` function.

If you want completely replace `Yii::$app->response` by your own component:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    \Yii::configure(\Yii::$app, [
        'components' => [
            'response' => [
                'class' => 'app\modules\mymod\components\apiResponse\ApiResponse',
                'format' => yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                'charset' => 'UTF-8',
            ],
        ]
    ]);
}
```

But i think that this is a bad idea to completely replace Response component of parent application in a module. The better way is **modify** Response behavior for your needs. For example You can use `EVENT_BEFORE_SEND` and build your own data structure in response:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    // you can use ContentNegotiator at the level of module
    // and remove this behavior declaration from controllers
    \Yii::configure($this, [
        'as contentNegotiator' => [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
            // if in a module, use the following IDs for user actions
            // 'only' => ['user/view', 'user/index']
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ],
        ],
    ]);


    // you can daclare handler as function in you module and pass it as parameter here
    \Yii::$app->response->on(Response::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND, function ($event) {
        $response = $event->sender;
        // here you can get and modify everything in current response 
        // (data, headers, http status etc.)
        $response->data = [
            'status' => 'Okay',
            'data' => $response->data
        ];
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, i did not want to replace the application response component through the module. 

Just to use the custom response component in the module.

Thank you!

Comment: @Jepi then use first option. If you'll replace app response component the `init` function of your module then it will affect only your module. To replace some component in entire application (include other components) replacement should be done in bootstrapping

Comment: @Jepi I meant that the parent application might already have its implementation of response component. For example, there can be initiated some services for logging or debugging that are common to all modules. By replacing a component within the module, you completely block the ability to customize this component for your module in the parent application. So if you expect that your module will be used in other applications, keep that in mind

Comment: I'm keeping that in mind. So i'll use the second option, and change the data attribute of yii\web\Response to match the custom result.

Comment: About using the first option, but still be able to customize the component in the parent application.
1. If i defined a response component in config/web.php
2. In the module init() i could get the $components_arr = this->getComponents();
3. Check if response component is configured
        array_key_exists('response', $components_arr)
4. If exists, configure app with it.
            \Yii::configure(\Yii::$app, [
                'components' => [
                    'response' => $this->response,
                ]
            ]);
5. Else, do nothing. Use the app component.
Is it ok?

Comment: @Jepi If component exists (I.e. it has been customized in parent app config) You are going to replace it (your step 4), else -- do nothing? Maybe You meant opposite? Anyway looks confusing. As for me, replacing entire parent application component (even if it will take effect only in range of a module) gives to a module very wide responsibility, and breaks "single responsibility" SOLID principle. I'd recomment you to use second option (inject response body postprocessing code using Event). May I ask You why do you need such envelope? Why can't you use standard HTTP statuses and headers?

Comment: It's not that i really need such an envelope. It's that i'm interested in understanding yii2. I had the custom response class working in a parent application, but then i tried to use it in a module and i wanted to understand what approaches i could use. Pros and cons.